# trying to print human readable ascii string

Tags: python, string, ascii

I am trying to print a string which is human readable ascii but not getting any output. What am i missing?

```
import string
file = open("file.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
data = data.split("\n")
for line in data:
    if line not in string.printable:
        continue
    else:
        print line
```

Comment: what's the content of the file?

Comment: `in` is substring search, so for example `'cat' in string.printable` is `False`.

Comment: @Norrius right, so what should I do to check if a line of ascii is human readable or not?

Answer (score 1):

If your file's content is text, you should read files like this:

```
import string
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if all( c in string.printable for c in line):
            print line
```

You must check every character individually to see if it is printable. There is another post about checking that string is printable: [Test if a python string is printable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636928/test-if-a-python-string-is-printable)

Also, you can read about context manager about how to open file right way: [What is the most pythonic way to open a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445910/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-open-a-file)

Comment: Yes, it is beter with generator.  With square brackets python will construct list with lines as elements and it consumes additional memory.